# Finding a string within a string with newlines ( \n )

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to find a string between two custom headers.

Below is the string I'm working with, and I want to be able to extract the part of the string between the "---BEGIN CGP MESSAGE---\n" and the "---BEGIN CGP KEY---\n", or any othe the other little header things.

```
---BEGIN CGP MESSAGE---\n
EoEZ1Qio8/BY/vl9iGblkg==\n
---BEGIN CGP KEY---\n
dOo23Ar23p4v6So70O65E6ImFnzuYrVro3nXFi5s4RUdczLITEDNcUefRiOgyEKWJKR/CW1DeLITPlT7RjV3FQRIz8sIdsW8Zuq9E4u6ad5n+EPxC80IfhdrThJPs/T6yuaVW3s+45mnyGMHvhEatwwkqtJZydfBKz3qb/JUkf0=\n
---END CGP MESSAGE---\n
```

Everywhere I looked suggested regex, and it was often formatted like this (I replaced the example they used with the parameters I wanted)

```
String str = sb.toString();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("---BEGIN CGP MESSAGE---(.*?)---BEGIN CGP KEY---");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.println(matcher.group(1).toString());
}
```

(sb is the string-builder that built the string above.)

Unfortunately, when I run this code, it doesn't print the line "EoEZ1Qio8/BY/vl9iGblkg==" that I want. I get no errors or anything; it just doesn't print anything in the console.

I don't know why, but using this exact regex code will not work for me. That's why I post this question, the solutions I've tried from this site do not work. Other answers are often variations of this code or just don't work for my purposes.

Oh, and I can't use the string splitting thing that relies on the integer location of a character. The strings between the headers will be of varying lengths, and so the program must be able to accommodate for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the pattern to consider linfeed for the dot.

```
Pattern.compile("---BEGIN CGP MESSAGE---(.*?)---BEGIN CGP KEY---", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: what's a good way to also create a string of the regex. What I mean I want to be able to instead of printing "EoEZ1Qio8/BY/vl9iGblkg==" have it as a string variable. defining a string variable in the "while" loop doesn't work of course.

Comment: @Ryuluce Define it outside of the loop. The loop is actually not really needed, you know that you will always have one match in your string.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the modifier `(?s)` to dot matches the new line character :

```
(?s)---BEGIN CGP MESSAGE---(.*?)---BEGIN CGP KEY---
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD2iV1/1)